CORS Issue with Dynamic Subdomains in Spring Boot Application
I am facing an issue with CORS in my Spring Boot application. I have several domains from which I can upload files without any problem:

http://localhost:4200
https://mydomain1.com
https://mydomain2.dev
https://admin.mydomain2.app

However, I encounter CORS errors when trying to upload files from dynamically generated subdomains, such as:

https://subdomain1.mydomain2.app
https://subdomain2.mydomain2.app

All other endpoints are working fine for dynamically generated sub domains. Only those endpoints in which I am sending a file to be uploaded to GCP throws cors error.
Stack Details:

Backend: Spring Boot
Frontend: Angular
Deployment: Pulumi and GCP

CORS Configuration:
Here is my current CORS configuration:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean(name = "corsConfigurationSource")
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList(
                "http://localhost:4200",
                "https://mydomain1.com",
                "https://mydomain2.dev",
                "https://admin.mydomain2.app",
                "*.mydomain2.app"
        ));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}

Issue:
The configuration works fine for the explicitly listed domains but throws a CORS error for any subdomain of mydomain2.app that is deployed by Pulumi.
Error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at
'https://backend.care-upload.mydomain2.app/apis/v1/staff/uploadImage/1'
from origin 'https://care-upload.mydomain2.app' has been blocked by
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource.

Question:
How can I configure my Spring Boot application to properly handle CORS for dynamically generated subdomains of mydomain2.app?
Additional Information:
I am using Angular on the frontend to handle file uploads, and the backend is deployed using Pulumi and GCP.
Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Try https://*.mydomain2.app instead of just *.mydomain2.app. See the doc of setAllowedOriginPatterns: supports more flexible origins patterns with "*" anywhere in the host name.

@jub0bs Thanks for the suggestion. I have already tried it but got same error

unclear but, I think its because you have overlapping COR patterns. Specifically https://admin.mydomain2.app and *.mydomain2.app - it should just be *.mydomain2.app and then update your security configure to specify a requestMatch to only allow access if authenticated or by role.

sorry, typo ment https://*.mydomain2.app not *.mydomain2.app

@TheoNeUpKID tried it but still same result

The error message indicates that https://care-upload.mysubdomain2.app is issuing the request, but nowhere in your CORS configuration do you allow arbitrary subdomains of mysubdomain2.app. Typo?

@jub0bs there was a typo in the question. I have updated my question
